# Access Internal Network (like ssh) via OPENVPN AssessServer having two VPN Client(one as VPN gateway and one user)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, routing, openvpn

My target is **access ssh to pc's connected to lan network**(say home network) via using OpenVPN Access Server with reverse VPN Coonections.
I had setup OpenVPN Client and OpenVPN AS Configuration as per given Tutorials
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7qr0laM8kA and https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/

Here are details,
[image]
OpenVPN Access Server is setup on Digital ocean having users as user12 and hturlte, and VPN Gateway is setup in Home network as hturtle and vpn user12 directly connected to internet having dynamic public ip.

VPN Subent :172.27.224.0/24
LAN home network subnet:192.168.1.0/24
VPN Gateway IP(connected to home lan):192.168.1.10.

Static Route on Router1 as
Gateway 172.27.224.0 subnet:255.255.255.0 gateway:192.168.1.10 Metric:2

In home network,pc1,pc2 and pc3 **can ssh to each other**

when user12 and hturtle is actively connected to vpn setup on openvpn AS,
**hturtle(vpn gateway) has vpn ip:172.27.224.130 and local ip:192.168.1.10**.

**user12 vpn id:172.27.224.131**.

user12 can ping all devices including hturtle(pc4),pc1,pc2,pc3.

**user12 can only ssh to hturtle via both ip 192.168.1.10 and 172.27.224.130**.

**user12 cannot ssh to other devices but pingable,Why?   Please guide me how add routing so that i can ssh to PC1 and PC2 **.

see screenshot below
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution,
Just have to add IPTABLES rules in VPN Gateway OS to get any services from VPN LAN Network.